# Bootstrap not working with UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET application that uses bootstrap as the front end framework. I will bundle the libraries I'm using through `ScriptBundle`, which looks like below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/masterPageScripts").Include(
        "~/Theme/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js",
        "~/Theme/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js",
        ....
    ));
```

And then I have a `ListView` that I want to put inside an `UpdatePanel`, so that it does not refresh the whole page. The ListView looks like this:

[image]

When I clicked on the "+" icon, the dropdownlist will disappear:

[image]

I tried to call again the `bundles` in the `pageLoad` function but it does not seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Reload js on partial postback
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '<%: Scripts.Url("~/bundles/masterPageScripts") %>',
                dataType: "script",
                cache: true
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you doing on Plus(+) icon click??

Comment: To add a new row in the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the loading of the scripts are not necessary. What I needed to do is to reload the `selectpicker`.

Here is how I solve it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {                
            $('#<%= updtPnlBran.ClientID %> .selectpicker').selectpicker();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`pageLoad` or `$(document).ready` are called only on the initial load of the page, not after an Async PostBack (content update inside an UpdatePanel). You need the `PageRequestManager` for that.

```
<script>
    var requestmanager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    requestmanager.add_endRequest(function () {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '<%: Scripts.Url("~/bundles/masterPageScripts") %>',
            dataType: "script",
            cache: true
        });
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `pageLoad` does get called after partial postback. I tried adding the requestmanager, but it still does not work.

Comment: I never had luck with this either. Had to downgrade bootstrap to 3.* and stop using bootstrap-select and went back to the old select2 dropdown.  Would love to see a working answer for this!

Comment: You have to find the bootstrap 4 jquery snippet that generates the dropdown list and execute it again after async postback.